# Convert string to time format more than 24 hours format ( [h]:mm:ss ) without incrementing day

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I need to convert string to time in hours format. I tried using the below But I didn't get the results that I expect.

```
inp_string = "70:30:00"
print(datetime.strptime(inp_string, "%H:%M:%S").time())
```

For this I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: time data '70:30:00' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'
```

If I enter the value of hours below 24 I'm getting good results;

```
new = '23:30:00'
print("value:",datetime.strptime(new, "%H:%M:%S").time())
print(type(datetime.strptime(new, "%H:%M:%S").time()))
```

output

```
value: 23:30:00
<class 'datetime.time'>
```

Like this, I have to convert a string into time format where the hours are greater than 24.

Comment: What is your expected result for "70:30:00"?

Comment: `"70:30:00"` is not a time (as on a 24h clock), it is a duration - in Python, you use [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) for that, not datetime.

Comment: I need to add two time so with input as string, it is complex to add "70:30:00" + "00:30:00" and get result "71:00:00"

Comment: you're looking to parse strings representing a duration to timedelta type, then you can do the arithmetic operations (addition etc.), then format the result back to string (output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write your own parser to convert your `str` to `timedelta` (or find a library that does this for you).

Assuming your duration is always like `HH:MM:SS`, you can use something like this:

```
import datetime

def parse_duration(s):
    return list(map(lambda x: int(x), s.split(":")))

inp1 = "70:30:00"
[h1, m1, s1] = parse_duration(inp1)
d1 = datetime.timedelta(hours=h1, minutes=m1, seconds=s1)


inp2 = "00:30:00"
[h2, m2, s2] = parse_duration(inp2)
d2 = datetime.timedelta(hours=h2, minutes=m2, seconds=s2)

res = d1 + d2

# Format res however you like
```

Answer (score -1):

```
inp_string = "70:30:00"
new_hour=(int(inp_string[0:2]))%24
new_string=str(new_hour)+(inp_string[2:8])
print(new_string)
print(datetime.strptime(new_string, "%H:%M:%S").time())
```

Comment: I think you didn't read the question well

Comment: You forgot `from datetime import datetime`